# Group the consecutive numbers from an array with series of numbers which are greater than 2 into subarrays using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

> Given an array `A = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10,0,1,1,2,4,10,6,7,3]`, group the  consecutive elements which are greater than 2 in to sub-arrays.
>
> The desired output is `result = [[2,3,5,6,7,8,10],[2,4,10,6,7,3]]`.
>
> Example: `A = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10,0,1,1,2,4,10,6,7,3]`
> Output: `result = [[2,3,5,6,7,8,10],[2,4,10,6,7,3]]`

Could anyone help with this question?

I have tried:

```
const a = [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 9];
const result = a.reduce((acc, current) => 
   const lastSubArray = acc[acc.length - 1];
    
   console.log(`${acc}-${current}`)
  
   console.log(lastSubArray[lastSubArray.length - 1]);
   if (current >2 && lastSubArray[lastSubArray.length - 1]>2) {
      acc.push(current);
   }

   acc[acc.length - 1].push(current);
   console.log(acc);

   return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What's the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a global variable to keep track of the indexes so that it's possible to detect when exists a gap between two numbers, which allows you to add another array. In combination, using ternary operators can make the code cleaner to test for conditions.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 10, 6, 7, 3];
let lastIdx = -1
const results = arr.reduce((acc, current, idx) => 
     (
        current > 2 ? (
            lastIdx + 1 === idx && acc.length ?
                (
                    lastIdx = idx,
                    acc[acc.length - 1].push(current), 
                    acc
                )
                :
                (
                    lastIdx = idx,
                    [...acc, [current]]
                )
        ) : acc
    )
, [])

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Logic getting failed when the first value is greater than 2 @testing_22

Comment: logic getting failed when the first value is greater than 2

Comment: It is true. You must also check if there is an element before pushing. Please see edit.